# Race condition between multiple instances of API(Express Node JS) deployed using PM2 Cluster mode

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, race-condition, pm2

I have developed **REST API** endpoints using **Express JS** and deployed on a server using **PM2 cluster mode**.
Currently there are 10 instances of API project running on the server.

In one of the Endpoint I am first checking if record already exists and if it does not then inserting a new record otherwise updating the same record. I am using **MongoDb** and **mongoose** as ORM in API project.

Currently when the endpoint is invoked twice with same parameters at the same time , 2 new records are getting created. I was expecting it to create only 1 record as I am checking in API if record is already created then do not insert it again and just update same record.

Please suggest  approach to fix this issue as duplicate records are getting inserted into DB .

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide a [minimal reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: what does logs show you?